# Jquery Binding Events to Multiple Textarea Instances on a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding, textarea

I have a script working exactly the way I need, just now, I am not able to replicate it on a page - The jquery takes textarea boxes and edits them based on buttons being pressed, however I need each textarea box to have it's own set of buttons. Here is my code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;" id="text">This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" id="button2" />

<br /><br />

<textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;" id="text">This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" id="button2" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function insertText(text) {
    var $textbox = $("#text");
    var textStr  = $textbox.text();
    var startPos = $textbox[0].selectionStart;
    var endPos   = $textbox[0].selectionEnd;

    // If set to true, the selection will NOT be replaced.
    // Instead, the text will be inserted before the first highlighted character.
    if (false)
    {
        endPost = startPos;
    }

    var beforeStr = textStr.substr(0, startPos);
    var afterStr  = textStr.substr(endPos, textStr.length);

    textStr = beforeStr + text + afterStr;
    $textbox.text(textStr);
    return textStr;
}

$(function () {
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        insertText("\n\nafter clicking");    
    });
    $('#button2').on('click', function () {
        insertText("\n\nafter clicking 2");    
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/0hmdu0ox/

Comment: you are using the same ids : *button1 button2* and *text*...If you change the ids, have you tried?

Comment: But if I do that, how do I update the function insertText as well?  How to I designate which textarea box the button is updating?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this version :

```
<textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;" id="txt1">This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="insertText('\n message1', 'txt1');" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" onclick="insertText('\n message2', 'txt1');" />

<br /><br />

<textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;" id="txt2"> This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me"  onclick="insertText('\n message1', 'txt2');" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" onclick="insertText('\n message2', 'txt2');" />
```

use only this function:

```
function insertText(mess, txtA) {
    var textbox = $('#'+txtA);

    var textStr  = textbox.text();
    var startPos = textbox[0].selectionStart;
    var endPos   = textbox[0].selectionEnd;

    if (false) {
        endPost = startPos;
    }

    var beforeStr = textStr.substr(0, startPos);
    var afterStr  = textStr.substr(endPos, textStr.length);

    textStr = beforeStr + mess + afterStr;
    textbox.text(textStr);
    return textStr;
}
```

**Targets for optimizations:**

if you can get the nearest textarea in the *insertText* function that will be great... then you don't need id for textarea and also you don't need to specify the id in the parameters, you will then be able to do something like this:

```
<textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;"> This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me"  onclick="insertText('\n message1', this);" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" onclick="insertText('\n message2', this);" />
```

And in function something like this:

```
function insertText(mess, btn) {
    var textbox = $(btn).prev('textarea');
    ....
```

Hope it will help you to find the best solution :)

Comment: Thank you for replying ... I was trying not to repeat the code multiple times for each button if possible because I may have like 10-20 textarea boxes on a page at one time.  Is there any other way?

Comment: yes it should be other ways of course... I'm thinking and maybe come with a better solution. I was thinking at generating this text arreas and make a general function for button clicking

Comment: Yes that is where I was getting stuck :\

Comment: I found a better solution, but I'm trying to optimize it now, and I will send it to you